# Linkedin OAuth2 authorization code error

Tags: rest, redirect, get, oauth-2.0, linkedin-api

I´m trying to connect via Linkedin Auth2 from a java web application:

1. Added my own app in linkedin.
2. Generate the authorization URL: https://www.linkedin.com/uas/oauth2/authorization?response_type=code&client_id=XXX&scope=r_basicprofile%20r_fullprofile%20r_emailaddress&state=DCEEFWF454Us5dffef424&redirect_uri=http://localhost:9090/springmvc/token.htm
3. Introduce my login/password for linkedin in the new popup.
4. Get back successful the request on the redirect_uri previus, and take the authorization code "code"
5. Generate the accessToken URL
6. Make a POST with: https://www.linkedin.com/uas/oauth2/accessToken?grant_type=authorization_code&code=YYY&redirect_uri=http://localhost:9090/SpringMVC/token.htm&client_id=XXX&client_secret=ZZZ
7. Get next error in response: {"error_description":"missing required parameters, includes an invalid parameter value, parameter more than once. : Unable to retrieve access token : appId or redirect uri does not match authorization code or authorization code expired","error":"invalid_request"}

I´ve verified url parameters are correct:
 - "code" is the token receive on step 4.

- "redirect_uri" is the same URL on step 2 and 4. I added this URL on section "OAuth 2.0 redirect URL" on my APP.
- "client_id" and "client_secret" are the "Client API" and "Secret API" on my APP.
- Time between first and second request is less than 20 seconds.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The value of your `redirect_uri` parameter must be URL-encoded, so at 6. do:

```
 https://www.linkedin.com/uas/oauth2/accessToken?grant_type=authorization_code&code=YYY&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A9090%2FSpringMVC%2Ftoken.htm&client_id=XXX&client_secret=ZZZ
```

and it need not be sent as a POST but as a GET.

Comment: sending as GET instead of POST worked for me. Thanks.

Comment: Its not working for me even if i'm using GET, Can you help me. I've posted my question `https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52501144/unable-to-get-access-token-linkedin-oauth`. Will you please look once

Answer (score 1):

If You Are Sending a Request For Access Token it must be POST Request

[Refer the OAuth Documentation](https://developer.linkedin.com/docs/oauth2#ux)

I actually Copied the Whole URL From My Eclipse Console To URL It is Still Valid

In Your Case The Problem is with URL Encoding As HanZ said .
You Have to Encode Your URL For Post Request.

Answer (score 0):

I too got bugged with this issue for long time. Please keep few things in mind which I did and eventually sorted it out.

1. Hit the api to get authorization code by using get request.
2. The authorization code has a life span of about 20 seconds, so its difficult to manually copy the code from the url and make a request for token access. You should do it pro-grammatically.
3. Make a post request for getting access token.
4. Most Important: Old linkedin applications that I had created was not working  and giving the above error. Create a new linkedin application and try. Doing this worked for me.

I assume that all the other parameters like client_id, secret, redirect_uri are correct.

please try and let us know.

Thanks.