# linkedin access token generation error

Tags: oauth-2.0, linkedin-api

When I try to generate access token using:

```
https://www.linkedin.com/uas/oauth2/accessToken?grant_type=authorization_code&code=xxxxxxxxxxx&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Fws-100945%3A9080%2FArtisWeb%2Findex.html&client_id=xxxxx&client_secret=xxxxx
```

it's throwing error as:

> {"error_description":"missing required parameters, includes an invalid
>   parameter value, parameter more than once. : Unable to retrieve access
>   token : appId or redirect uri does not match authorization code or
>   authorization code expired","error":"invalid_request"}.

Could you guide me on this issue?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Linkedin OAuth2 authorization code error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29804501/linkedin-oauth2-authorization-code-error)

Answer (score 0):

The URL itself looks correct so it must be the `code` that is expired or reused. Make sure the `code` is used immediately after you receive it and use it only once.

Also make sure that you URL-encode in fact all parameter values, including `client_id` and `client_secret` if/since they may contain URL-unsafe characters like '&' and ' '.

Comment: yes...i tried using immediately only..still same error

Comment: I just browse on site to get any reference.My issue is same as https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29804501/linkedin-oauth2-authorization-code-error?s=16|0.1763 ,hope this clarifies my question

Comment: updated answer with note about url-encoding of all parameter values

Comment: ,we need to use code within 10secs,it has taht short lifespan

Comment: just need to confirm,i read somewhere taht access token generated is quit short ,merely 10characters-length,however,mine is a way lenghty-179characters.

Comment: Usually the code is quite short and the access token is long because a lot of tokens may live at the same time. In any case both are opaque to the client so you cannot and must not assume anything.

Comment: @HansZ. any luck in resolving that error? i tried same way, but still getting error,  Can you share request call for access token, like what should be sent in body, what should be sent in header.

Comment: @HansZ., sharing my question post, can you help me for the same `https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52501144/unable-to-get-access-token-linkedin-oauth`